# Unexpected behaviour with enum values as types (in Typescript)

Tags: typescript, types, enums

I am having troubles with understanding the way values of enums members can be used to define types in Typescript.

I understand in Typescript you can define unary types by specifying a primitive object as a type value. And enum members have numeric value associated with them.

In the following example I am aliasing the value of an enum members as the type `newType`. Everything makes sense, except what happens on the last line with the variable `d`.

```js
const enum blah {
    test = 1,
};

type newType = blah.test;

var a: newType = 'a'; // ERROR (Type '"a"' is not assignable to type 'blah'.)
var b: newType = blah.foo; // ERROR (Property 'foo' does not exist on type 'typeof blah'.)
var c: newType = blah.test; // WORKS
var d: newType = 123; // WORKS...???
```

The last assignment works without error. What's an explanation for that?

(The original example came from my colleague @michaelkyriacou during a discussion about unary types in Typescript.)

Comment: Isn't `newType` in your example just a `number` so your example would make sense?

Comment: @Raven what I expect is that the type is the value `1`, not a `number`. That is what happens when you do `type newType = 1`.

Answer (score 1):

All numbers can be assigned to an enum member. Just like all numbers can be assigned to an enum. e.g.

```
const enum blah {
    test = 1,
    foo = 2
};

const x: blah = 567; // allowed
```

Comment: The type of the variable in my example is not the enum, but the enum member. Also, I expect that to be a fixed value and not a type number.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that you are referring to a value from a variable.

What you are doing is essentially:

```
let x = 1 // type of x is number, not 1
type z = typeof x // the z is of type number.
```

Comment: I don't see why that should happen, I'd expect `type newType = blah.test` to be equivalent to `type newType = 1` and not `type newType = typeof 1`.